# What are the benefits of making a perk Legendary?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

If I bump up a skill like crafting and get it to 100 and then make it Legendary, do I still have the ability to craft everything like Dragon Bones or do I lose that and have to build it back up?

Comment: I do not believe this is a duplicated question so I'll answer it - you DO have to build it back up. It is an utterly ridiculous feature of Skyrim that anyone would have to "relearn" a skill after getting it to 100. Why? They.... forgot it? What are the benefits? You can redistribute the points and gain higher levels, but it's more realistic to use an uncapper instead.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Skyrim wiki](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Skills_(Skyrim)), the skill reverts to novice.

> Note that you still have to go far enough to re-unlock the perks; you do not get to keep them, and cannot, for instance, re-level smithing quickly by making ebony or dragonbone items at a low smithing level.